# "process is not defined" in gatsby-browser?

Tags: environment-variables, gatsby

I'm trying to insert an environment variable "GATSBY_EX_ENV" inside a window property to make it available to external scripts.

and GATSBY_EX_ENV is defined in my environment files alongside numerous other env variables which are accessed at runtime within React components. So I know it's declared correctly and that our env variables are generally working.

Right now in my gatsby-browser.js I am doing this:

```
export const onClientEntry = () => {
  window.onload = () => {
    var EXT = location.host
      .split('.')
      .filter(x => x !== 'www' && x && x !== DOMAIN && x !== 'com')[0];
    // additional parsing
    window._external.properties = { env: EXT };
  }
}
```

This does work, but it's clunky and brittle. I want to replace that URL parsing with:

`window._external.properties = { env: process.env.GATSBY_EX_ENV }`

But when I do, my local develop site fails to load with the error "process is not defined". Should I be placing this code in a different method?

Comment: What do you mean by "dev build"? It's a `gatsby develop` or a `gatsby build`? (I assume the first one but just to be sure)

Comment: develop, not build. I clarified the question